# Supervisord - restart several processes if one crashes

Tags: supervisord

Can supervisord restart a group of services when of them crashes?

I have 3 services (processA, processB and processC) which are unrelated. 
When one of them crashes for any reason, I need the 3 services to be stopped and restarted in order, for example:

- 1st processA
- 2nd processB
- 3rd processC

Groups don't seem to have this utility.

Comment: any success in solving this thing? did you manage to do it?